# Find out the currently logged in user in Django

Tags: django, authentication

I have created a list of 5 users. How do I find out which user has logged in currently? Also please mention, if there is any way to find out if the super-user has logged in?

My requirement is, I want to restrict the access of certain pages in the templates only to the superuser.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Current user is in request object:

```
def my_view(request):
    current_user = request.user
```

It's django.contrib.auth.models.User class and it has some fields, e.g.

- is_staff - Boolean. Designates whether this user can access the admin site;
- is_superuser - Boolean. Designates that this user has all permissions without explicitly assigning them.

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.1/topics/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User

So to test whether current user is superuser you can:

```
if user.is_active and user.is_superuser:
    ...
```

You can use it in template or pass this to template as variable via context.

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like you should be using the [built-in permissions system](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#the-permission-required-decorator) for this.

Comment: Does Django store the name of the currently logged in user in some attribute, So that i could grant access  to my pages based on that (I am new to django)

Comment: The user is stored in `request.user`. From there it's just a matter of accessing the attributes on the `User` model.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [user_passes_test](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#limiting-access-to-logged-in-users-that-pass-a-test) decorator for your views.  Django snippets has a related decorator:

> These decorators are based on
>   user_passes_test and
>   permission_required, but when a user
>   is logged in and fails the test, it
>   will render a 403 error instead of
>   redirecting to login - only anonymous
>   users will be asked to login.

http://www.djangosnippets.org/snippets/254/